# Unable fetch Products in TransientModel odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, odoo, odoo-11

So far i had read many questions but i am sure that i am total a mix up because i am unable understand how to use Search at odoo TransientModel.
I had written a code that get **Active_ids** from **self**

```
context=self.env.context.get('active_ids')
```

I am supposing these actives_ids as 
`product_tmpl_id` but when i tried to use them

```
  product_recs = produtc_obj.search([('product_tmpl_id', 'in', context)])
    print(product_recs)
    result = {}
    for rec in product_recs:
        print(rec.default_code )
        result[rec.default_code ]
```

but its always return

```
result[rec.default_code ]
KeyError: '1'
```

Here is my full code

```
import logging
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import Warning
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class product_export_to_rakuten(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'rakuten_ftp.export_product'

    @api.multi
    def export_products(self):
        # check for more than one orders.
       # print(self.env)
        context=self.env.context.get('active_ids')
        produtc_obj = self.env['product.product']

        product_recs = produtc_obj.search([('product_tmpl_id', 'in', context)])
        print(product_recs)
        result = {}
        for rec in product_recs:
            print(rec.default_code )
            result[rec.default_code ]
```

Here is the Error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 647, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 307, in _handle_exception
        raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 689, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 339, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 332, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 933, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\http.py", line 512, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "C:\Odoo_Source_Codes\odoo11\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 934, in call_button
        action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
      File "C:\Odoo_Source_Codes\odoo11\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 922, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\api.py", line 689, in call_kw
        return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "C:/Odoo_Source_Codes/odoo11\odoo\api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Odoo_Source_Codes\odoo11\custom_addons\rakuten_ftp\wizard\export_product.py", line 22, in export_products
        result[rec.default_code ]
    KeyError: '1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine with the Transient Model, the problem is that you're trying to read a dictionary value whose key doesn't exist yet. I mean, the `default_code` of the first product you get in the loop is *1*, and you're telling Python: I want to read the value of the key *1* of the dictionary `result`, but this one is empty, so you get the error (you need to fill it in first).

You can reply the error in a Python console, this is what is happening to you:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> result['1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '1'
```

You should do something like this to make it work:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> result['1'] = 'Your value'  # result.update({'1': 'Your value', })
>>> result['1']
'Your value'
```

Comment: Thanks  for your valuable time . StackOverflow ki Jai Ho